# How can I horizontally center 3 divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, center

So I have 3 cards that I am going to put my projects inside, and I need them to be perfectly centered horizontally. I have tried many things but none have worked so far.

Here is the code for the cards.

```css
.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card .topImage {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-content: center;
}

.topImage {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.card .topImage img {
  height: 220px;
}

.card .bottom {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .bottom p {
  text-align: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.card-1 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.card-1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give `text-align:center` to parent of all `.card`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use flexbox. Make a container for the cards and put display: flex; on it and then justify-content: center to center them no matter the size of the new container div

```css
    .card {
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      width: 290px;
      overflow: hidden;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .card .topImage {
      display: inline-flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 220px;
      overflow: hidden;
      align-content: center;
    }

    .topImage {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }

    .card .topImage img {
      height: 220px;
    }

    .card .bottom {
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .card .bottom p {
      text-align: left;
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      padding-left: 20px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #444;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    }

    .card-1 {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
      transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    }

    .card-1:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .card-container {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="card-container">

    <div class="card card-1">
      <div class="topImage">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <p>Project 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-1">
      <div class="topImage">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <p>Project 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-1">
      <div class="topImage">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <p>Project 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Flexbox rocks for these kind of position problems. Definitely read more if you are unfamiliar: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox this is easy. On the element that contains your divs just add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;`:

```css
.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card .topImage {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-content: center;
}

.topImage {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.card .topImage img {
  height: 220px;
}

.card .bottom {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .bottom p {
  text-align: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.card-1 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.card-1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent with `text-align: center`

```css
.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card .topImage {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-content: center;
}

.topImage {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.card .topImage img {
  height: 220px;
}

.card .bottom {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .bottom p {
  text-align: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.card-1 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.card-1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card card-1">
    <div class="topImage">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Project 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-1">
    <div class="topImage">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Project 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-1">
    <div class="topImage">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Project 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `translateX` and `left` rules to position them.

```css
.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.card .topImage {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-content: center;
}

.topImage {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.card .topImage img {
  height: 220px;
}

.card .bottom {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .bottom p {
  text-align: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.card-1 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.card-1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card card-1">
  <div class="topImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Project 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```